# Cannot configure Marlin 2/0.X bugfix on Ender 5 pro, 4.2.7 board with BLTouch 3.1

Tags: bed-leveling, firmware, bltouch, creality-ender-5

I am new to 3D printing and recently purchased a Ender 5 Pro. I came and the 8 bit 1.15 board was broken (couldn't run extruder). I upgraded to a 32 bit Creality 4.2.7 and also purchased a BLtouch 3.1 bed leveling probe.

I downloaded the stock firmware from Creality for the Ender 5 Pro and it seemed to work fine. I was having problems leveling the bed (it is high in the center) so that is why I bought the BLTouch. The 4.2.7 has a dedicated plug for the BLTouch, but, I cannot find any firmware to make it work properly. I, after a lot of head scratching, was able to get Marlin 2.0 edited with MS Visual Studio adding code for the BLTouch. Now when I try to home, the bed moves down, the probe moves to the back right position (like regular Z-Stop homing), then goes to the center of bed, the BLTouch cycles 2 times, but, the bed never comes up! It just stays where it is/was. The LCD says, "STOPPED" and then "Home Z". I seem to be the only one with a BLTouch 3.1 attached to a 4.2.7 board on the Ender 5 Pro. Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you say you "added code" for the BLTouch, what do you mean? Normally, adding a BLTouch just involves uncommenting the relevant setting in Marlin, not adding anything.

Comment: Your correct, My Bad. I modified some of the Marlin statements in the Configuration.h file to produce a compiled .bin file that made my UNOFFICIAL combination of parts work correctly together. No actual code additions or subtractions just configuration tweaks.  I'm working on a list that will show all the changes I made to to this file to get my setup working. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? Last night I flashed my Ender 5 Pro to use Marlin 2.0.x and I am having the same exact experience. I used the Marlin Firmware Service to get my bin file autocompiled for me and I beleive it is correct (I don't think my knowledge level is up to par yet to compile my own code). I ended up going back to the stock Ender 5 Pro firmware from Creality to get the machine working again....

Comment: @BillMiller - Use `diff` to easily produce a [diff file](https://www.lifewire.com/diff-file-2620661) of the config changes that you made. If possible, please post it here as an answer.